# How to check update of one URL

Tags: python

I need a code to check the updates of a ulr in Python

Ulr :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.gp.apexlegendsmobilefps

Is there a way like this to check for url updates? I want to know when it will receive an update
In fact, this page probably receives updates from the database. .

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help], especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: AFAIK the only method is to regularly fetch the page and check the data received for changes. That's kind of the nature of the internet. Just maybe google.com provide some kind of API for checking this kind of thing, but that would be specific to google, and you'd have to research that.

Comment: Also do NOT tag programming languages if you don't have a question that relates to ONE specific language of which you can show a code example.

Comment: When asking a question like this, try to break down the problem. How would you do this by hand? If you had to solve the problem without code, what steps would you do? Try to turn that procedure into steps performed by code, and if you have trouble getting the code to work, ask questions about that on StackOverflow. Just asking people an open question like this comes down to asking them to do your work for you, and that's not what SO is for.